# RewriteRule add query if directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Assumption**

Redirect everything to index.php except the Images folder (if file exists).
For example:

*/main/test => index.php?controller=main&action=test*

*/image/exists.png => image/exists.png*

*/image/another.png => index?controller=image&action=another.png*

**Current code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-f"
    RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/.*$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&v1=$3&v2=$4 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&v1=$3&v2=$4 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&v1=$3&v2=$4 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&v1=$3 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&v1=$3 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Adverse reaction and the reason why I please help**

If I'll put the path to an existing folder you will be redirected to a very strange path. For example if I'll write URL like *localhost/image* in browser I get URL like *localhost/image/?controller=Image*. Finally - it loads a good file but looks ugly.

*/image => index.php?controller=image* (But in browser's URL field: */image/?controller=Image*)

PS If I used Firefox I got good URI without Query. I think it's because Firefox adds a slash at the end of the URL without an extension.

How to "repair" it?

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is all those **(.*)** as they are greedy, the first one in a REGEXP will consume all characters up to the end of the line. If you only want a REGEXP that consumes up to the next **/** use **([^/]*)** or **([^/]+)**.

Next to exclude real files you'll be wanting to use the [SKIP](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) directive eg. Stick the following at the top of the rule set:

```
# Skip the next 10 RewriteRule is the requested file physically exists, in the image
# directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^image/ - [S=10]
```

Comment: Incidentally, "L" does not cause a skip in the case where a pattern match?

Comment: In a different way. **L** comes into effect once a redirection HAS occurred.